# AngularJS & BootstrapUI: Switch tab by button only works once

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want the user to be able to click on a "next" button in order to jump to the next tab.

This is the affected HTML (I have actually stripped everything out and tested it, but it still only works once):

```
<body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <form name="orderBrochures" novalidate>
            <div ng-controller="TabController as tabCtrl">
                <tabset justified="true">
                    <tab heading="Prospektauswahl" class="tabHeading" ng-controller="OptionController as optionCtrl" active="optionsTab">


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" ng-click="next()">Weiter</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br>
                    </tab>

                    <tab heading="Pers&ouml;nliche Angaben" class="tabHeading" active="personDetailsTab" id="personDetailsTab">

                    </tab>
                </tabset>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is the related `TabController`:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('orderBrochures', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('TabController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
        $scope.next = function() {
            $scope.personDetailsTab = true;

            $location.hash('personDetailsTab');
            $anchorScroll();
        }
    }]);
})();
```

The first time I click on the button everything works fine. The second time I click it'll just do the scrolling, it won't change the tab.

I have checked the example code at [Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) (scroll down to "Tabs") but I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This is due to the prototypal inheritance gotcha described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out what was wrong, although I don't understand why. If you use a `$scope` variable as value for `active` it will only detect the change of the expression once.

However, if I use the attribute of a controller (like `tabCtrl.personDetailsTab`) it detects the change of the value everytime.